# Java heap space OutOfMemoryError when binding a .jar in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, dalvik

When following the steps on the Xamarin site for [Binding a Java Library](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/) to create a binding project for the ArcGIS for Android 10.2.2 I am able to get the project compile. However, when I attempt to deploy and run the project I get the following error:

```
COMPILETODALVIK : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL error :
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod$2.addToUses(SsaMethod.java:474)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod$2.visitPhiInsn(SsaMethod.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.PhiInsn.accept(PhiInsn.java:323)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.forEachInsn(SsaBasicBlock.java:990)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.forEachInsn(SsaMethod.java:729)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.buildUseList(SsaMethod.java:452)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.getUseListForRegister(SsaMethod.java:641)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SCCP.addUsersToWorklist(SCCP.java:116)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SCCP.simulateStmt(SCCP.java:538)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SCCP.simulateBlock(SCCP.java:208)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SCCP.run(SCCP.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SCCP.process(SCCP.java:92)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.runSsaFormSteps(Optimizer.java:160)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:100)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:73)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:487)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update:** 
As [Blueberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1418898/blueberry) said, you can now edit this option through Xamarin/Visual Studio editors:

> In Xamarin Studio, you can now go to:
>
> > Project Option > Build > Android Build > Advanced (tab)
>
> In Visual Studio, you can now go to:
>
> > Project Properties > Android Options > Advanced (tab)
>
> You will find Java Heap Size there, which you could set to 1G.

In Xamarin 4.6 and later you can specify the Java Maximum Heap Size (`JavaMaximumHeapSize`) which allows you to override the "[default java heapsize which is sometimes too low to compile some .jar files.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8137#c14)"

To specify the value, edit the .csproj of the Android project (not the binding project) and add this at the top (where 1G is the value you'd like to set)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For additional information see [this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/7323/#Comment_7323) on the Xamarin forums.

Answer (score 16):

In Xamarin Studio, you can now go to:

> Project Option > Build > Android Build > Advanced (tab)

In Visual Studio, you can now go to:

> Project Properties > Android Options > Advanced (tab)

You will find Java Heap Size there, which you could set to 1G.